# Search and replace strings in 2GB text file size

Tags: python

I want to search and replace some file paths in text files.
on average the my file size is above 2 GB.

for example:
i have a folder in my D drive "D:\LargeFilesFolder".
and all files exist in the folder.

```
"D:\LargeFilesFolder\large_file_v001.txt"
"D:\LargeFilesFolder\large_file_v002.txt"
"D:\LargeFilesFolder\large_file_v003.txt"
```

In all text files i want to search for `"X:\path\link\here"`  and replace with `"Y:\here\link\path"`

What is the best optimized python way to read and edit big text files in python..?

Comment: Iterate over the lines and write a new file. Then move the new file over the old file.

Comment: For Iterate over lines     with open(large_text_file, 'r') as txt_file  this will load entire file but since the file size is big. i want to do it with a memory optimized way.

Comment: No, it will not read the entire file into memory. Try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over the lines and write a new file. Then move the new file over the old file.

```
with open(outputfilename, "w") as outputfile:
    with open(inputfilename, "r") as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            # replace in line and write to outputfile

shutil.move(outputfilename, inputfilename)
```